# SCCM Alter WSUS Maintenance features via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, wmi, sccm

Microsoft Endpoint Configuration Manager > Administration > Site Configuration > Site > (Right click site name) Configure Site Components > Software Update Point > WSUS Maintenance

There are three options in here, 'Decline expired updates in WSUS according to supersedence rules', 'Add non-clustered indexes to the WSUS database', and 'Remove obsolete updates from the WSUS database'

I want all three of these options enabled. The first one can be done via `Set-CmSoftwareUpdatePointComponent -EnableCallWsusCleanupWizard`
I can't figure out how to do the other two.

For so many other things in SCCM, I use WMI Query. If I use:

```
[hashtable]$wmiObject = @{
    Namespace = "root\sms\site_$( $sitecode )"
    Computername = 'Localhost'
    Class = 'SMS_SCI_ScProperty'
}

$mecmObjects = Get-WmiObject @wmiobject | ?{ $_.ItemName -match "SMS_WSUS_Configuration_Manager" }

$property = $mecmObjects | ?{ $_.PropertyName -match 'Obselete Updates' }
$property.Value = $true
```

it'll change the value from 0 to 1, but `$property.Put()` results in a "Generic failure" error.

The CMQmiQuery for this is :

```
SELECT * FROM SMS_SCI_SCProperty 
WHERE SiteCode = `"$siteCode`" and ItemName = `"SMS_WSUS_CONFIGURATION_MANAGER|SMS Site Server`" and PropertyName = `"Call WSUS Delete ObseleUpdates`"
"@
Invoke-CMWmiQuery -Query $query
```

Would really appreciate any advise/help here.
Thank you